# Powershell variables in command not working

Tags: powershell, mysql

I've tried a ton of different variations of this, but I can't get it to work. I am trying to run mysqldump to export a database (in this case called global).

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> &"$mysqlpath\mysqldump.exe -u$mysqluser -p$mysqlpass --databases global | Out-File $env:TEMP\database_backup\global_$timestamp.sql -Encoding UTF8"
& : The term 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe -ubackup -pbackup_password --databases global | Out-File C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\database_backup\global_2013-12-11T11:47:28.sql -Encoding UTF8' is
not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.     Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ &"$mysqlpath\mysqldump.exe -u$mysqluser -p$mysqlpass --databases global | Out-Fi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File... -Encoding UTF8:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

It looks like it is being exploded into the proper variable names, but I can't get it to run.

**UPDATE**: So that was the right answer, I had a : in the timestamp. My other problem was solved by putting the variables inside double quotes (")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling Powershell to run an EXE named

`&"$mysqlpath\mysqldump.exe -u$mysqluser -p$mysqlpass --databases global | Out-File $env:TEMP\database_backup\global_$timestamp.sql -Encoding UTF8"`

So remove the quotes (`"`) and try again. Like so,

`& $mysqlpath\mysqldump.exe -u$mysqluser -p$mysqlpass --databases global | Out-File $env:TEMP\database_backup\global_$timestamp.sql -Encoding UTF8`

Comment: On top of that, colons aren't valid as parts of a file name in Windows unless they're part of the drive designation, so it's likely that your Out-File statement will fail, too.

Comment: I changed it to 
&$mysqlpath\mysqldump.exe -u$mysqluser -p$mysqlpass --databases global | Out-File $temppath\database_backup\global_$timestamp.sql -Encoding UTF8

But still get

Out-File : The given path's format is not supported.
At line:1 char:74
+ &$mysqlpath\mysqldump.exe -u$mysqluser -p$mysqlpass --databases global | Out-Fil ...
+CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Comment: Your timestamp variable $timestamp seems to be expanding to 2013-12-11T11:47:28 which won't work because you can't have a : in the file path.

Comment: Your right, I didn't even think about $timestamp. I'm still doing something wrong after I fixed timestamp. It looks like it's not using the $mysqluser variable.

mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user '$mysqluser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
PS C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2> $mysqluser
backup